# What is the quickest way to burn different ISO files to many flash drives?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I frequently have to burn many **different** ISO files to flash drives. Currently, I am using a program called ISO to USB to do this - but the issue is that it takes around 20 minutes per drive. I have to burn about 10 drives each day, each with different ISO files. What's the quickest way for me to do this?

**Note:** since I'm using separate ISO files, USB duplicators are not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: If your USB is big enough, and you use those ISO a lot, you could use something like a multi-boot USB - something like [yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) that can boot multiple ISOs from a single USB. Depends on your specific need, having a multi-boot USB may work. But note, in the end it depends on your PC read/write speed to the USB drive. If it really does need 10 minutes to transfer the amount of data from the PC to the USB, then you can't speed it up. The most you can do is plug in multiple USB, and burn multiple ISO at the same time.

Comment: What is the size of your ISOs?

Comment: I would also consider a USB 3.0 drive and port, burning an ISO image to a quality USB 3.0 drive could cut your time down significantly, probably under 5 minutes pretty easily.

Comment: You could create a separate folder with only ISO's.So the initial ISO creation would be one time. I use ImgBrn for this. Then you could simply copy the ISO's to any new USB on demand. There are many ways to copy as well (drag/drop, dos commands, ftp...).

Comment: My apologies - I should have mentioned that I'm burning to multiple different flash drives as well.

Comment: @ejbytes the ISOs are already created, there's just many of them and I don't know how many of which ones I'll have to burn in advance.

Comment: Are your ISOs locally stored, or on some cloud?

Comment: @AliChen they're locally stored, on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

20 minutes is 1200 seconds. Even if the ISO size is 4GB, it makes the write speed under 4MB/s. This is a sustainable write speed of a typical low-end el-cheapo USB pen drive.

You need to invest into good USB 3.0 pen drives, and obviously have a USB3.0 host to do the pen writing.

Keep in mind that not all pen drives are made equal. Some loss of write performance can happen in USB-NAND bridge, and most critical part is in architecture of storage chips. Some higher performance pen drives may have "dual-channel" architecture, better ones have **quad channel usb flash drive** topology, with reported write performance up to 100MB/s - 150MB/s. This will cut your write time to under 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux you can use the `dd` command:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX
sudo dd if=/path/to/ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync
```

`sdx` is your usb device.

The first command will unmount your drive. The next command will burn the specified ISO to the USB drive.